# DOM manipulation inside a callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, socket.io

I am building a client that is connected to a `socket.io` server. I have this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    Desktops.onData(function (desktops) {
        var desktopsList = $("#desktops");
        $.each(desktops, function (id, desktop) {
            console.log(desktop.name);
            desktopsList.append('<option value="' + id + '">' + desktop.name + '</option>');
        });
    });

    Sockets.connect();
});
```

The callback inside `Desktops.onData` gets called when the data comes back from the server. I then take this `data(desktops)` and try to append it into a select element, which is used with a [Bootstrap plugin](http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select). In the HTML side I have:

```
<select id="desktops" class="selectpicker" data-live-search="true">
</select>
```

I know that the problem is not in the data because `console.log` works. I also know that the problem is not with my HTML or jQuery code because when I try to append to the `select` outside of the callback, it works. So it must be something about doing jQuery inside callbacks. What can I do to make that jQuery work?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you see appended elements via inspection tools? Can you provide example as I can't see why it may not work (you have only one `#desktops` element on page, right?)

Comment: I have just checked and i can actually see the appended elements via inspection tools, but they are not rendered on my screen.
Why is that?

Comment: If using some plugin for dropdowns, maybe it's not updating html?

Comment: @Justinas i am using a bootstrap plugin for making selects look more "pretty", you think that the problem could lie there? Is there a way for me to update the html manually?

Comment: Please check console

Comment: @Arik that's the issue. Depending on the plugin, you either need to use the methods it provides for adding options or re-initialise the plugin after adding the `option` elements. Which plugin are you using?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/
How do i re-initialize the plugin? Is there a general way to do it or does it depend on the plugin?

Comment: It depends on the plugin. I added an answer for you with a demo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the plugin you've stated that you're using ([Bootstrap Select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/methods/#selectpickerrefresh)), you need to call the `refresh` method on it for it to recognise that new `option` elements have been added to the underlying `select`. Try this:

```js
Desktops.onData(function (desktops) {
    var desktopsList = $("#desktops");
    $.each(desktops, function (id, desktop) {
        console.log(desktop.name);
        desktopsList.append('<option value="' + id + '">' + desktop.name + '</option>');
    });
    desktopsList.selectpicker('refresh'); // update the bootstrap select here
});
```